# How to install vCenter on ESXi host where both are on different IP?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I need to install vCenter server on ESXi host, but there is a **constraint** that- **vCenter and ESXi host are required to be on different IP ranges**, i.e vCenter server is on one machine and ESXi host on other.

Comment: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vcsa.doc%2FGUID-56C3BA9A-234E-4D81-A4BC-E2A37892A854.html

Comment: @yagmoth555 can vcenter server and esxi host be on different IP addresses ?

Comment: yeah, but it mean that those vlan must be able to talk to each other.

Comment: Yes that is possible. We have the same setup which you are asking and it working fine.

Comment: @vembutech can you please tell me how to do so, as yagmoth555 have suggested to use "vSphere Web Client", and I have no idea about it

Comment: I think you're out of your depth if you don't know this most basic of steps - have you read NONE of the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the ESXi server on a physical machine, and configure the network. Then you can download the Vsphere client using the IP through browser.

[image: check this image]

You can control the ESXi host through this tool.

[image: VSphere] [image: CSphere Client]

After this you can install VCenter server in VM or in physical machine. Then you can add this ESXi host into VCenter and manage it.

It Is not mandatory to keep both the servers is same VLAN. The VCenter server and ESXi host IP's should ping each other that is enough.

If you need more details on implementation get back to me.

Comment: The question asker cannot get to the point of being able to deploy the VC!

Comment: @vembutech I have used this vSphere client tool, but in that case both ESXi host and vcenter were on same VLAN. What changes are required when they are on different VLANs?

Comment: how to add the remote ESXi host after installing vCenter?

Comment: You need steps to add an ESXi host in VCenter ?

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than you'd think - but you need a few things in place.

All you need to do is use the .NET/Windows client to connect to your host, navigate to the Network config and add a new tagged port group for the VLAN the VC is going to live. You need to expose this VLAN up the appropriate trunks and obviously sort out the routing in your switches or upstream router but this will allow you to deploy your VC into the correct VLAN and allow it to route to the ESXi host management addresses. By the way it can be worthwhile putting your hosts and VC in the same VLAN as there can be quite a lot of ports to open depending on what extra vmw products you want to use.